# Adding a twitter icon in html page

Tags: html, css

How to generate the twitter , facebook and youtube icon as in the top of the website 
https://store.linefriends.com/ 
If I inspect the element I see the following html : 
`<li><a href="https://twitter.com/_LINEFRIENDS" title="LINE FRIENDS INC on Twitter" rel="me" target="_blank" class="icon-twitter"></a></li>` 
Not sure how that icon gets generated from this html line as there is no image etc here

Comment: You can just use an `<img>`. It doesn't matter what Joe Random website does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such icons can be generated using an icon library. The most popular choice is `FontAwesome`. If you want to add links, you can enclose `i` tag with an `anchor` tag, with `href` attribute. You need to add a bit of styling to it.

```css
a{
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<div class="container">
  <span><a href="https://www.twitter.com"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a></span>
  <span><a href="https://www.facebook.com"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a></span>
  <span><a href="https://www.youtube.com"><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></a></span>
  <span><a href="https://www.instagram.com"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a></span>
</div>
```

You can get the code for `link` tag from [cdnjs](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/font-awesome)

You can search for all icons on their [website](https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery&p=1)

---

You can also download icons and use `img` tag, but using an icon library, makes things a lot easier.

Comment: Thanks this works perfectly. But how do I put a link for each span item too ? Like for twitter I want it to go to www.twitter.com

Comment: @Ronitsharma You can use `a` tag for it. See my updated answer above.

Answer (score 1):

You use a font family ("Turbo" as I can see) that contains web icons inside.

The icon is generated from the class `icon-twitter`. Inside this `<a>` element there is a `.icon-twitter::before` pseudo element that contains the content value     `content: "\ea96";`. This value is being interpreted to this icon.

So, if you want to change this icon you have to remove the `icon-twitter` class and put an `<img>` element with your custom image file ( I would recommend to be an svg file for better load time performance ).

Answer (score -1):

1. you will need to check each css file found in inspect element via view source for class icon-twitter. (with code like )

Or

1. Use font awesome for this.  More details are available on https://fontawesome.com/
2. Fon awesome alternatives are available on https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.hongkiat.com/blog/free-font-icons-to-bookmark/amp/ OR  https://alternative.me/font-awesome

Or

You can use images to achievs this with  tag